# How to use GraphQL supbscription with react-relay?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs

How can I use the GraphQL subscriptions with React-Relay ?

I found a solution using [relay-subscriptions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/relay-subscriptions) package, but I'm still looking for a solution provided by Relay only without any extra packages.

PS: I'm using a graphql hosted plateform provided by [Scaphoold.io](https://scaphold.io/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a new tutorial on how you can setup GraphQL Subscriptions with react.

https://scaphold.io/blog/2016/11/09/build-realtime-apps-with-subs.html

I haven't spent enough time with subscriptions in relay yet but they are super easy to setup with Apollo Client, can run alongside relay, and will work with Scaphold immediately! I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using this package?

[GraphQL Relay Subscription](https://github.com/taion/graphql-relay-subscription)

Seems promising, but I haven't actually tried it out myself.